# Roslyn - get ConstructorDeclaration given System.Type

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using [CodeGeneration.Roslyn](https://github.com/AArnott/CodeGeneration.Roslyn). I have defined the following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
[CodeGenerationAttribute(typeof(DependsOnGenerator))]
[Conditional("CodeGeneration")]
public class DependsOnAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type Type { get; }

    public DependsOnAttribute(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

Now inside `GenerateAsync` I need to get the `ConstructorDeclaration` of type received in `DependsOnAttribute`

```
private Type _dependencyType;

public DependsOnGenerator(AttributeData attributeData)
{
    _dependencyType  = (Type)attributeData.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
}

public Task<SyntaxList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>> GenerateAsync(TransformationContext context, IProgress<Diagnostic> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var constructorDefinition = Magic(context, _dependencyType); // ?????????
}
```

How to implement the `Magic` method?
(It's a first time I'm touching Roslyn and Code Generation so please give as much details as you can.)

Comment: @HansPassant the Type will be always in different assembly so there is no chicken here. It looks like [SymbolFinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.findsymbols.symbolfinder?view=roslyn-dotnet) can be the answer but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Its not clear what you want. Do you mean `ConstructorDeclarationSyntax`? What would the value of `constructorDefinition` be if we have `DependsOnAttribute(typeof(int))` for example?

Comment: You are casting the value of the constructor argument to `Type`, I think it will be `INamedTypeSymbol` which cannot be cast to `Type`.

Comment: If you are trying to get the constructor of the type passed to `DependsOnAttribute`, you need to think about the possibility that you do not have the source code for the type.

Comment: See the Locations property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isymbol.locations?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_ISymbol_Locations . Its can help you get to the source code of the type if it exists in the current solution.